# How to show column values with PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PDO, but cant seem to work how to return values

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categories_url = ?');
$stmt->execute([$url]);
if($stmt->fetchColumn()>0) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $row['categories_name'];
    echo 'test';
}
```

The 'test' echos ok, but the $row values dont show. I tried `print_r($row)` too, and nothing shows. I thought I needed to set the $row variable using the fetch() method, is this not right? What is wrong here?

** UPDATE **

I removed the if statement, for fetchColumn, and it works, why is that? Does it matter if fetchColumn method comes before fetch()?

If so, how do you set the $row variable only if there are results?

Comment: `fetchColumn` will move the result pointer to the next row, `fetch` will do that again, if you only have 1 result then fetch won't get anything from the `fetch`.

Comment: OH! so how do show the values, only if there are any results?

Comment: `if (($row = $stmt->fetch()) != null) { /* show stuff */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, then access the element you want by name.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['categories_name'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think execute expects an array  like

```
 $sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
```

just follow some example on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
```

and try [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead of fetch if multiple rows

Comment: $url is a variable, and it is an array within the []